Linux OS for STM32MP151 Cortex A7
I have an STM32MP151AAC3 processor that are connected to an eMMC. The processor architecture is a Cortex A7.
The processor have a USB OTG available to connect so it can be flashed over USB.
STMicroelectronics provides no Linux OS for the STM32MP151 series. Only for STM32MP157. It's only a minor difference between them, but still not possible to flash the STM32MP151 with a Linux OS from STM157.
Question:
I'm looking for an Linux OS that works on STM32MP151 series and it must be flashed over USB OTG and the flash memory is an eMMC.

https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32mp151.html#tools-software

@ChanganAuto Sorry, but that's only for STM32MP157-products.

Exactly. If the vendor doesn't provide it then it doesn't exist. What would be the logic of officially providing for one and not other if there were some community, unofficial, effort already?

@ChanganAuto Idk, I have spoken to ST and they say that even them have problems by understanding how to build Linux for the STM32MP series
